# Why use templateContext in Azure Pipeline Yaml

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#use-templatecontext-to-pass-properties-to-templates

I’d never noticed this functionality before but I’m struggling to understand the use case. I don’t feel it’s hugely well explained as it really just shows an if switch.

I’ve done much the same type of thing as this example before with the if conditionals but it referenced a variable or parameters.

Why do I want to use templateContext over those methods of if-ing off a variable or parameter.
I seen the original blog post and again don’t feel it gave a good example.

Can anyone give me more examples please or compare to parameters or variable.  ?

there’s clearly something I’m missing as you’d not create this functionality without a need to fill.
thank you !

Much appreciated